# How to use glob to find thumbnails

Tags: php, regex, glob

Say I upload a file called myimage.jpg and I generate thumbnails of this image that append width x height to the filename. I might have a directory of images that looks like this:

```
myimage.jpg
myimage-100x50.jpg
myimage-500x250.jpg
myimage-430x300.jpg
```

When I want to delete this image I need to delete all of the thumbs as well. ow would I use glob to find the original image and all of the thumbnails but not any other images that may be in the directory?

Comment: Why not use the same logic you used to generate the new file names?

Comment: The images are generated dynamically with an image helper. There could be an infinite amount of sizes created. I need to make it so that no matter what sizes have been made I know they will all be deleted.

Comment: Ah, I thought these were always going to be the same set of thumbnails. If they always start with `originalfilename-`, why not search for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in the end:

```
// find all images that match the filename
foreach (glob(myimage.*) as $filename) {

    // use regex to filter out any that have a similar name and are not thumbs
    if(preg_match("/(\myimage-\b)[0-9]\d*x[0-9]\d*(\b.jpg\b)/", $filename)) {

        // delete the thumb
        unlink($filename);
    }
}

// delete the original image
unlink(myimage.jpg);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might work for you.

```
$images = glob('myimage*.jpg');
foreach($images as $image):
    delete($image); //whatever function you use to delete
endforeach;
```

Comment: I think this would work but this could potentially delete an image by mistake if an image is called myimage-2.jpg for example. It needs to do a better pattern match e.g [filename][hyphen][any number][x][any number][extension]